# Is there any functions like "require" in Squirrel-lang?

Tags: squirrel

I try to import some package using "require"... because of the Squirrel-lang coming from Lua.

But I found that both there is nonthing in both "squirrel3" and "sqstdlib3"..

So I do it like this :

```
// foo.nut

local foo = {}

return foo
```

```
// main.nut

local foo = loadfile("foo.nut")

foo.bar()
```

Also, there is no "dostring"

.....
Do I need to implement a package manager myself?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking out https://github.com/inlife/squirrel-require, might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

`dofile` should do the trick ([documented here](http://www.squirrel-lang.org/squirreldoc/stdlib/stdiolib.html#dofile)).

I tried the following:

```
// foo.nut
local foo = {function bar(){print("bar!")}}
return foo
```

and

```
// main.nut
local foo = dofile("foo.nut")
foo.bar()
```

then got this result:

```
C:\Users\me\squirrel3\bin>sq.exe main.nut
bar!
C:\Users\me\squirrel3\bin>
```